# Customize date display format? [Android 7]

Tags: 7.0-nougat, localization

**How can I change global date format in Android 7.1.1?**

I want to continue using **en-US** locale setting, but with ISO date format **YYYY-MM-DD**. And change long format into **DD. MMMM YYYY** (e.g. 22. october 2017).

I know that date format change is not possible via menu items in the user inferface. **But perhaps is there some file in the filesystem where I can specify it?**

Comment: I'm afraid, no.

Comment: This question arises since Android 6 (where the corresponding option was removed – see [How to change date and time format on Marshmallow?](/q/135743/16575)), and for other languages as well (for me it e.g. truncated the year to 2 digits in some apps, and choosing a different locale didn't help) – so a more general answer covering that as well would be great. BTW: this is *not* Samsung specific, unfortunately (just saying as you chose that tag).

Comment: @Izzy – thanks for note on the scope, I removed Samsung tag. And yes, maybe someone with enough reputation could become an [Altruist](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges) :)

Comment: According to [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k56PCh8YrYE) one could simply *add another language* to the existing one (that guy ended up with "English (India)" as first and "English (US)" as second language). That way it seems one can play with different locales while keeping the language. Apart from that, all I found matches what the answers here and on the linked question already said. Still wondering why that option was removed – and not brought back despite of people complaining.

Comment: @Izzy – we all are *searching the web*. But isn't there anyone who simply understands Linux and points to proper place where the setting is stored? I also [asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406337/customizing-of-regional-settings-in-android) on Unix and Linux SE. I would expect that there are many developers who – if they do not already know the answer – simply look at the code (it is all open source, isn't it?) and extract the information from logic of the code.I am [doing similar examination](https://superuser.com/questions/1259111/notepad-new-1-file) in Windows software, so >>

Comment: >> I do not quite understand that no one already checked and explained such a relatively simple thing in Android/Linux world. I am able to do that but with lower effectivity as I am only a guest at that platform.

Comment: "isn't there anyone who simply understands Linux" – sorry, that won't help much in our context. While Android runs on top of a Linux *kernel,* the system is much different from that. In the Linux world, locale settings are managed via the `LC_*` environment variables. `adb shell env` doesn't show any of them being present on my Android devices. There *might* be some central database entry one could tweak (`settings.db` seems gone with Marshmallow, so I don't know where to look), but noone told me yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69144/discussion-between-miroxlav-and-izzy).

Answer (score 1):

Try `en-CA` locale setting.

It uses well-formed English, as well as ISO units and formats.

Comment: This one is better. Long date format is still wrong. Are there files in file system where these settings can be manually edited into desired form (similar to Windows Registry) or is asking about such advanced changes off-topic on this site? I think we both know that formats for current locale are actually stored somewhere and can be changed there.